# $(\mathbb{Z}_{n}^{*},.)$ is a group $\iff n$ is prime.

Tags: group-theory

Here $\mathbb{Z}_{n}^{*}$ means $\mathbb{Z}_{n}-{[0]_{n}}$

My attempt:

$(\leftarrow )$

$p$ is a prime, then, for every $[x]_{n},[y]_{n},[z]_{n}$ $\in (\mathbb{Z}_{n}^{*},.)$ are verified the following:

1) $[x]_{n}.([y]_{n}.[z]_{n}) = ([x]_{n}.[y]_{n}).[z]_{n}$, since from the operation . we have $[a]_{n}.[b]_{n}=[a.b]_{n}$ and . is associative in $\mathbb{Z}$.

2) There is an element $e$ such that $[x]_{n}.e = e.[x]_{n} = [x]_{n}$, since $ [x]_{n}.[1]_{n} = [x.1]_{n} = [x]_{n} = [x.1]_{n} = [x]_{n}[1]_{n}$

But I don't know how to check the inverse property, neither how to do the $(\rightarrow)$ part.

Thanks!

Comment: For the inverse use euclidian algortihm, it gives for $gcd(x,y)=1$ an equation $ax+by=1$. For the $\rightarrow$ part suppose $n$ isn't prime, $d\mid n$ and calculate $d\cdot n/d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $n$ is composite.

Then $n=ab$ for some $a,b\in\{2,\dots,n-1\}$.

Take one of them, for example $a$.

Consider the residue class $[a]$.

If $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ was a multiplicative group, then $[a][c]=[1]$ for some $c$.

It means that $ac\equiv 1\pmod{n}$, but since $n=ab$, it implies that $1$ is divisible by $a$.

Contradiction!

Answer (score 1):

$\impliedby$ If $n$ is prime, then it is coprime to every non-zero element, hence $gcd(a, n) = 1$ for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$. This implies $as + nt = 1$ for some $s, t \in \mathbb{Z}$ by Bézout's identity. It follows that $[a][s] = [1]$, hence every non-zero element in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is invertible.

$\implies$ If $n$ is not prime, then it has a positive divisor $x$ which is neither $1$ nor $n$. We then have $xy = n$ for some $y \in \mathbb{N}, y < n$, so $[y] \neq [0]$. This means $[x][y] = [0]$. Now assume, $[x]$ had an inverse $[x]^{-1}$. Then we have $[x]^{-1}([x][y]) = [0]$ and by the associative law $[y] = [0]$, which is a contradiction.